# How is it possible to be a baronet and not a peer?

Tags: united-kingdom, nobility

I probably still haven't grasped what peerage really entails. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_peers_and_baronets) says:

> The Baronetage of Nova Scotia (a British hereditary title, but not a peerage) had been devised by King James VI of Scotland in 1624 as a means of settling Nova Scotia. Except for Sir Thomas Temple, almost none of them came to Nova Scotia, therefore they are counted as British, not Canadian.

Comment: I now see that I should have researched more. But I was told (incorrectly) that, while in France pairs de France were rare, in England all nobles were peers. The question received negative rating. Should I delete it? It would destroy the answerer's high rated reply!

Comment: No, don't delete it.

Comment: Kind of the same way it is possible to be a person and not a rock; the definitions are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace thanks, I understood it already.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The ranks of the [UK peerage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peerage_of_the_United_Kingdom) are duke, marquess, earl, viscount, and baron.

A [baronetcy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baronet) is an hereditary title awarded by the British Crown, and (with a couple of exceptions) is the only British hereditary honour that is not a peerage.

Baronetcies were originally introduced in England during the 14th century. They were used extensively by [King James I/VI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_VI_and_I) as a means of raising funds or incentivising other projects - like the settlement of Nova Scotia.

Comment: Note also that Peers could sit in the House of Lords, baronets were commoners and could only sit in the House of Commons if Elected.

Comment: Do (Duke)
Men (Marquess)
Ever (Earl)
Visit (Viscount)
Boston (Baron).

Comment: @PieterGeerkens We had a similar mnemonic, except Baron was "Belfast" rather than "Boston". :)